# Printf/scanf replacement methods: some feedback/advice needed

Tags: objective-c, printf, scanf, xcode4

I've recently been writing some basic command-line programs (I want to keep my skills sharp over the summer), but `printf` and `scanf` have been starting to annoy me. I'm not a wonderful C programmer, and having to get into `printf`/`scanf` and their instabilities (or even worse, `fgets` and their ilk) isn't exactly putting me in a comforting setting (for this reason exactly, I love `NSLog`, with its comforting default namespace and its automatic `NSString` and `NSObject` parsing).

Much to my disappointment, though, NSLog doesn't have a counterpart function, and prints a lot of extra 'junk' (time, function name, etc., along with a newline at the end), which defeats a lot of the purpose in my using it. So I decided to sit down for a different kind of programming exercise and write functions to replace printf and scanf that would meet my needs.

And voila, I came up with my own `NSInput.h` file, containing two functions: `NSPrint()`, and `NSScan()`. These two functions are modeled much after printf and scanf, but also handle `NSString`'s. I know I'm treading on sacred namespace here, but I couldn't resist (`IFPrint` and `IFScan` just sound terrible!).

Now, while I'm really happy that I have working code (for which you can find the source [here](http://snipt.org/Xkoo)), I know that it's not efficient (much to my surprise, though, `NSPrint` is several times more efficient than `printf` under LLDB in Xcode 4, but that's beside the point). I need some advice on how to make the functions better, and more efficient. `NSScan`, for example, converts the `va_list` it recieves into an `NSPointerArray`, and uses `NSScanner`'s to scan through the format and input strings, so I know there's a lot of room for improvement.

**Basically,** what I want to know is, are there any glaring mistakes I made that could and should be fixed? Is there anything huge that I missed? Should I just be called spoiled and go back to using `printf` and `scanf`? Please tell me, I'm looking for input here (pun not intended!)...

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: What is it you're looking for in a printf-like function that you can't get with [NSString stringWithFormat:]?

Comment: The one glaring omission I noticed is the lack of a test suite.

Comment: @Seamus: if you look at the source, that's exactly what I do.
@Greg: I've actually never done test suites before, so I guess now would be a good time to try, right?

Thanks for the responses!

Comment: Whoops.  My brain was thinking sprintf, and I was trying to figure out why you were reinventing the wheel, as a thin wrapper over an existing wheel.  :)

Comment: Don't call them NSPrint and NSScan.  No, just don't!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My thoughts:

- Don't call them NSxxxxx, NS is reserved for Cocoa and Foundation.
- Both functions should be modified to accept a `FILE*` i.e. you should be modelling the interface to `fprintf()` and `fscanf()` for more flexibility.
- Your printf function would probably be better if you used `fputs()`

e.g.

```
void NSFPrint (FILE* fp, NSString *format, ...) 
{
    // Create the variable argument list.
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);

    // Using NSString, parse the argument list and convert it to a C string.
    fputs([[[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:format arguments:args] autorelease] UTF8String], fp);
     va_end(args);
}
```

- Consider adding support for input and output in encodings other than UTF-8.
- Your scanf replacement mixes C buffered IO and Unix unbuffered IO on stdin.  This might be bad.
- Your scanf replacement reads up to the end of the line even when it doesn't need to.  I haven't checked carefully, but if the scan format does not consume the entire line, it looks like you are discarding input.  This might be bad.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I'll be implementing them as soon as possible.

Just one question, though. What do you mean by my using both the C buffered IO and Unix unbuffered IO, or at least, how can I avoid this problem?

Comment: I've updated my code a little (http://snipt.org/XmL) to reflect your suggestions (I've renamed the functions `IFPrint` and `IFScan`, they now take file pointers as arguments, `IFPrint` now uses `fputs`, and I've replaced `read(0, NULL, 1)` with `fgetc` - is that what you meant with the buffered/unbuffered IO?). Hopefully, I'm heading in the right direction.

Comment: Yes.  The `read()` function call is a Unix system call and it reads direct from the file descriptor using nothing but Unix IO calls.  `fgets()` is a C library function which operates on a `FILE*`.  file pointer.  The file pointer maintains a buffer and fgets only reads from the physical file when this buffer is exhausted.  And when it does read, it reads in a large block.  That way, doing `fgetc()` is not as inefficient as you might think because most of the time it gets the character from an internal buffer.

Comment: Now, how about this: http://pastie.org/1081717? I realized that if I ever had to use `IFPrint` to write to a file, I'd be much more likely to work with an `NSFileHandle` than a `FILE *`, so I worked accordingly. `IFPrint` will keep the same efficient code as before (printing to `stdout`), while `IFFPrint` will print using an NSFileHandle. I split up `IFScan` in the same way, letting the user scan through an `NSFileHandle` with a given offset.

Do you think this was worth the effort, or am I just wasting my time?