# Is it possible to NSLog() without the time and date stamps, and the automatic newline?

Tags: objective-c

Does NSLog() have variants that print without the time and date stamps, and the automatic newline?

Thanks. Now with following code, I can print NSString, cString, or objects:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

  NSString *s = @"Hello, World!";
  NSDate *today = [NSDate date];

  NSLog(@"%@", s);
  printf("%s at %s", [s UTF8String], [[today description] UTF8String]);

  [pool drain];
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use [**`MLog.h on GitHub`**](https://github.com/InderKumarRathore/MLog)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use `printf()` instead of `NSLog()`

Comment: Does printf() support NSString?

Comment: @Stephen no, you would have to use something like `printf("%s %s\n", [someString UTF8String], [[someObject description] UTF8String]);`

Comment: No, it's a C function. So you would have to convert NSString into a char array. So `printf([myString cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]);`

Comment: you should really use a format string in case there's a `%`

Comment: @cobbal good point, I forgot about that :P

Comment: In my case I had **NSLogv**, i managed to replace it with **vprintf** for cleaner logs

Answer (score 17):

This code will work

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    #define NSLog(FORMAT, ...) fprintf(stderr,"%s\n", [[NSString stringWithFormat:FORMAT, ##__VA_ARGS__] UTF8String]);
#else
    #define NSLog(...) {}
#endif
```

Comment: Very nice. @marshaul, why is stderr bad to use? I don't know where NSLog normally writes to.

Comment: It's not "bad", it's just missing the point of having separate STDERR and STDOUT streams. The convention is to use STDOUT for "normal" output and STDERR for "abnormal" output (errors etc.). Since the user may explicitly redirect the streams (such as by redirecting STDERR to /dev/null), it doesn't make sense to pipe everything to STDERR. Console/terminal output is output, and errors are errors. The point of all that is that STDOUT is (should be) the normal/default case.

Comment: Also I might point out that, when considering the original question, the extra "meta"data output by NSLog is actually perfectly appropriate for error-type messages, whereas "normal" console IO for user interface is where nice, clean output is going to really be preferable. And, as I mentioned, this is precisely the case where STDOUT should be used.

Comment: Can we have this answer in Swift?

Comment: I believe you should not have ";" at the end of the line

Answer (score 16):

It bothered me too, so I wrote a function to replace `NSLog()` and `printf()`:

```
void IFPrint (NSString *format, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);

    fputs([[[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:format arguments:args] autorelease] UTF8String], stdout);

    va_end(args);
}
```

Then, you can just use it instead of `NSLog()` (e.g. `IFPrint(@"Current date: %@", [NSDate date])`), but it won't print out any timestamps or a newline, and you don't have to mess around with C strings and arrays, and whatnot. It's pretty handy, I'd say.

If you want, check out my full code (I've also written a replacement for fprintf, scanf, and fscanf) [here](http://pastie.org/pastes/1093703/).
(There's also an SO topic about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436129/printf-scanf-replacement-methods-some-feedback-advice-needed)).

Answer (score 6):

Define a macro

```
#if __has_feature(objc_arc)
  #define DLog(format, ...) CFShow((__bridge CFStringRef)[NSString stringWithFormat:format, ## __VA_ARGS__]);
#else
  #define DLog(format, ...) CFShow([NSString stringWithFormat:format, ## __VA_ARGS__]);
#endif
```

And use this macro in you code like

```
NSLog(@"Content with time stamp");
DLog(@"Content without time stamp");
```

Here is the output of console

NSLog->`2014-01-28 10:43:17.873 TestApp[452:60b] Content with time stamp`
DLog  -> `Content without time stamp`

---

## P.S.

If anyone wants Custom Logs which gives you more info like method name / line number etc. can download the open source [**`MLog.h on GitHub`**](https://github.com/InderKumarRathore/MLog).

Comment: @Charles Thank you, I was just about to do that. I can't believe that edit was approved. I voted to reject with the comment "The fact that it's a link makes that clear. This edit is blatant self-promotion that doesn't add any value to the answer."

Comment: Calm down guys, iOSDeveloperTips you have a good site and instead of giving any comment or whatever, you should have contacted me and I would have helped you too. But the idea of `DMCA` has changed my mind and now I have improved my answer in terms of ARC.

Comment: This doesn't show UTF8 non-English letters correctly. It instead displays their unicode number (or whatever it's called) like `\u006z`.

Comment: Not sure why it did, but it instantaneously slowed down my application. The loading took forever. Granted I am doing a lot of NS logs at load time. So I removed it.

Comment: @pankaj I never tried it and hence I don’t know whether it slow down the app or not.

Answer (score 4):

I like the Itai's solution.  I just modified the code to use CFShow under ARC environment.

```
void CFLog(NSString *format, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);

    CFShow((__bridge CFStringRef)[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:format arguments:args]);

    va_end(args);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

the FIRST thing I do on ANY project is drop in (my condensed version of) [this class](http://borkware.com/rants/agentm/mlog/)... which gets rid of *ALL the NONSENSE* in `NSLog`…  Place this at the top of an `.m` file - and your console output will be **PERFECT**.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <stdio.h>
#define MLogString(s,...) \
    [MLog logFile:__FILE__ lineNumber:__LINE__ \
        format:(s),##__VA_ARGS__]
@interface MLog : NSObject { }
+ (void) logFile:  (char*) sourceFile lineNumber: (int) lineNumber format: (NSString*) format, ...;
+ (void) setLogOn: (BOOL)  logOn;
@end
#ifndef NDEBUG
extern void _NSSetLogCStringFunction(void (*)(const char *string, unsigned length, BOOL withSyslogBanner));
static void PrintNSLogMessage(const char *string, unsigned length, BOOL withSyslogBanner){ puts(string); }
static void HackNSLog(void) __attribute__((constructor));
static void HackNSLog(void){ _NSSetLogCStringFunction(PrintNSLogMessage); }
#endif
static BOOL __MLogOn = NO;
@implementation MLog
+ (void) initialize { char * env = getenv("MLogOn");
     if (strcmp(env == NULL ? "" : env, "NO") != 0) __MLogOn = YES;
}
+ (void) logFile: (char *) sourceFile lineNumber: (int) lineNumber format: (NSString *) format, ...; {
    va_list ap;    NSString *print, *file;
    if (__MLogOn == NO) return;   va_start(ap, format);
    file  = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: sourceFile                  length:strlen(sourceFile) encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    print = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:format arguments: ap];
    va_end(ap); // NSLog handles synchronization issues
    NSLog(@"%s: %d %@", [[file lastPathComponent] UTF8String], lineNumber, print); return;
}
+ (void) setLogOn: (BOOL) logOn { __MLogOn = logOn; }
@end
```

Comment: Is that AppStore safe?