# Customise NSLog so it shows less info

Tags: cocoa, xcode, logging, nslog

by default NSLog outputs a long string before the requested output,

e.g:

```
NSLog(@"Log message");
```

Outputs to the console:

```
2011-04-15 11:23:01.692 MyAppName[23160:903] Log message
```

I know I can add the filename and line number to the log, but how do I get rid of all the date, time and app name that appears before the message?

I find it really clutters the console in Xcode making it harder to find the information I'm after.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to NSLog() without the time and date stamps, and the automatic newline?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487226/is-it-possible-to-nslog-without-the-time-and-date-stamps-and-the-automatic-new)

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely the FIRST thing I do on a new project.  `NSLog(…)` has *diarrhea of the mouth*.   Here is a basic macro that lets you get some **peace and quiet**.. AND log basic objects without the annoying `NSLog(@"%@", xYz);` syntax (instead you just `NSLog(xYz);`).

```
#define NSLog(fmt...) NSShutUp(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,fmt)
#define UTF8FMT(fmt,argL) \
       [NSString.alloc initWithFormat:fmt arguments:argL].UTF8String

void NSShutUp(const char*func, id fmt, ...) {
    if (![fmt isKindOfClass:NSString.class]) 
    // it's not a string (aka. the formatter), so print it)
      fprintf (stderr, "%s: %s\n", func, 
       [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",fmt,nil]UTF8String]); 
    else {      va_list argList;     va_start (argList, fmt);
      fprintf (stderr, "%s: %s\n", func, UTF8FMT(fmt,argList)); 
      va_end  (argList);
}   }

/*  SAMPLE RUN */

int main (void) { NSString *a; NSNumber *b; NSArray *c;
    NSLog(a = @"Ahh, silence."    );
    NSLog(b = @(M_PI)             );
    NSLog(c = @[@"Arrays, baby!"] );
    // Old syntax still works.
    NSLog(@"%@ * %@ * %@",a,b,c);
    return 0;
```

}

<kbd>OUTPUT</kbd>

```
int main(): Ahh, silence.
int main(): 3.141592653589793
int main(): (
    "Arrays, baby!"
)
int main(): Ahh, silence. * 3.141592653589793 * (
    "Arrays, baby!"
)
```

Comment: I'd strongly suggest giving your custom logging macro a different name. Redefining NSLog will be confusing for people reading your code in the future.

Comment: @alex, seems you have not understood why it is absolutely essential to work with a format string in NSLog. I recommend to read up some articles about application security, how user supplied or wrong log data can crash an application or leak sensible information, not to mention code injection via stack overflows etc. If you don't care about all that in your application then it is probably ok to ignore otherwise basic application design rules.

Answer (score 0):

i would recommend that you start using a better alternatives to NSlog like SOSMAX or NSLogger.
Here is a bit overview of both of them 
http://learning-ios.blogspot.com/2011/05/better-nslog-ing.html