# How do I disable the dates in the XCode debugger?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging

In Xcode, the debugger lists the date next to each outputted line. I really want to reduce the amount of visual "noise" in the debugger, so how can I disable the dates from showing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `printf()` instead of `NSLog()`, but its a bit tricky.
Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487226/is-it-possible-to-nslog-without-the-time-and-date-stamps-and-the-automatic-ne), where you can find more info on this.