# 2012-08-09 17:29:13.988 LogTest[8186] How to avoid of printing this sentence at the output window while Using NSLog in linux?

Tags: objective-c

How to avoid of printing this sentence at the output window while Using NSLog in linux?

2012-08-09 17:29:13.988 LogTest[8186]

Comment: I think you should clarify what you are asking. NSLog is part of Apple's Foundation library, how are you using it on Linux?

Also: what exactly do you mean with "output window"? How are you running your application? If you are running your application from within XCode then you are not on Linux and the output pane is intended to show all output, including errors and logs: this is how XCode works.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to NSLog() without the time and date stamps, and the automatic newline?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487226/is-it-possible-to-nslog-without-the-time-and-date-stamps-and-the-automatic-ne)

Answer (score 1):

Use `printf` instead of `NSLog`. It probably has the same Parameters, but won't print the Timestamp before your Message.