# Objective-C Terminal output window

Tags: objective-c, window, output

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to NSLog() without the time and date stamps, and the automatic newline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487226/is-it-possible-to-nslog-without-the-time-and-date-stamps-and-the-automatic-ne)

This might be a dumb question, but yet I'm not able to find the answer.

When my program ends in objective-c, each time the NSLog prints something it writes the date and time when this output was written.

How do I tell X-Code not to print such information?

I get this on my screen:

```
--2013-01-11 18:57:53.016 GraphicObject[3084:403] -

|***2013-01-11 18:57:53.019 GraphicObject[3084:403] |

|***2013-01-11 18:57:53.020 GraphicObject[3084:403] |

|***2013-01-11 18:57:53.021 GraphicObject[3084:403] |

---2013-01-11 18:57:53.022 GraphicObject[3084:403] -
```

And Im trying to print this:

```
-----
-***-
-***-
-***-
-----
```

Thank you all!

Comment: printf() should work, give it a try!

Comment: Don't use `NSLog` if you don't want its output.

Comment: answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3487226/1354100), duplicate of that question i think.